# Is there a way to make sure an Indy 9 socket connection is truly broken (Delphi 6 application)?

Tags: delphi, sockets, indy-9

I have a Delphi 6 application that exchanges audio data over a socket with an external hardware device.  The hardware device has a problem internally where sometimes its internal buffer processing slows, especially during long periods of use, and nasty delays creep into the audio streams.  This is a significant problem since the audio data frequently underlies a two way real time conversation between people.  However, breaking the connection and re-establishing it fixes the problem.

I know how to close/disconnect a socket with Indy, that is quite easy.  My concern is that some connection caching mechanism in Indy or the Windows socket layer itself may defeat my disconnect efforts if I try to re-connect too quickly.  Is there a way to make sure that the socket connection with the external hardware device is truly broken?  Better asked, is there a way to make sure that my re-connection attempt forces the creation of a fresh new socket (handle?) rather than re-using the old socket connection?

The external hardware device only "resets" if a brand new connection is created, probably because it flushes its internal queues and starts fresh (speculation on my part since I don't have the source code for the device).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy will not prevent you from re-connecting immediately. The only time Windows will do so is if you are assigning the same local port for the client to bind to each time. In that case, you have to wait for Windows to release that port for re-use. You can manually set the socket's linger option to disable Windows' delay and release immediately. Or don't assign a local port, and a random port will be used on each (re)connect.

Comment: I'm not worried about problems re-connecting, I am worried that the old socket handle/connection will be re-used "behind my back" (or perhaps never really even broken in the first place) and therefore the external hardware device I am trying to disconnect from will not even see a disconnect event.  I want to make absolutely sure the external device sees the connection break and therefore discards the old data structures associated with the previous connection.  Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: The old connection will not be reused.